# Selenium - can´t find select-element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I try to automate this web page:
https://www.crownandcaliber.com/pages/sell-my-watch-iq#top

I am using the following code, which works fine till the select-element on the page:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

if __name__ == '__main__':
  WAIT = 5
  link = "https://www.crownandcaliber.com/pages/sell-my-watch-iq#top"
  ua = UserAgent()
  userAgent = ua.random
  options = Options()
  # options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')                               
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
  options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')   
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)                 
  driver.get (link) 
  time.sleep(WAIT)

  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()
  time.sleep(WAIT)
  print(f"Try to close info window...")
  try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Close']").click()
  except:
    pass
  time.sleep(1)
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//select').click()
```

When i run this code i get the following error:

```
Try to close info window...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\ymarket1ng\checkClocks.py", line 50, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//select').click()
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\Normal\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1153, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\Normal\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 400, in execute 
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\Normal\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 236, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)
```

When I inspect the site I find the single element with the XPATH "//select"

So why is this not working when running it with Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That element is inside the iframe. You need to switch to that iframe in order to access it.
This should work:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

if __name__ == '__main__':
  WAIT = 5
  link = "https://www.crownandcaliber.com/pages/sell-my-watch-iq#top"
  ua = UserAgent()
  userAgent = ua.random
  options = Options()
  # options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')                               
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
  options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')   
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)                 
  driver.get (link) 
  time.sleep(WAIT)

  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()
  time.sleep(WAIT)
  print(f"Try to close info window...")
  try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Close']").click()
  except:
    pass
  time.sleep(1)
  iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'consumer')]")
  driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//select').click()
```

**UPD**
Here is how you can see an [iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynwbz.png)

Comment: Yes now it is working - thank you very much - but how can i know that an element (which i found on the "normal" way with xpath when inspecting) can´t be found in selenium cause it is in an iframe...? Is there some way to check this when inspecting the page and trying out the xpath for selenium?

Comment: When you open the dev tools (F12) you can see the HTML of that page. in case there is an element with tag name `iframe` between the body and the desired element - this means that your desired element is inside an iframe. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok - thanks - but why is the xpath not working? When i input the xpath the element is found - when i do the same search in selenium it is not found (and i have to first switch to the iframe and then can do the search like you showed it to me). 

Why is iframe different than the other tags?

Comment: Read here https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handle-iframes-in-selenium/ or any other similar tutorial.